# Update mysql timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

I have a table with a field:

> 'last_modified - timestamp NOT NULL'

- I set the default value to the current timestamp. However this only works when updating or inserting from phpMyAdmin and not from my script.

I have tried

```
$sql = sprintf("UPDATE %s SET timestamp=now(), %s WHERE id='%s'", $table, $implodeArray, $_POST['id']);
```

and it still doesnt seem to work. How can I make the timestamp update when I update or insert by table from a script?

Also heres a sample of the scripts output:

> UPDATE about SET timestamp=now(), page_header = 'Page header goes here', sub_header = 'Sub header goes here', content_short = 'This is where a short description of the about page goes', content = 'This is where the full content description goes' WHERE id='1'

Comment: do not `timestamp=now()` in your query if you have set its default value to current timestamp.

Comment: so remove the default value and it should work?

Comment: @juergen thats a microsoft post. not really the same thing...?

Comment: Yes Alex, if you plan to update the timestamp manually remove the default value.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

May be I misread,but your column name is **last_modified** (typed *timestamp*), so the query should be:

```
UPDATE about SET last_modified=now(), 
page_header = 'Page header goes here', 
sub_header = 'Sub header goes here', 
content_short = 'This is where a short description of the about page goes', 
content = 'This is where the full content description goes' 
WHERE id='1'
```

Comment: Tried to use now() but it only saves date

Answer (score 1):

if you use a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html) as your table or columnname then you need to quote it

```
$sql = sprintf("UPDATE %s SET `timestamp`=now(), %s WHERE id='%s'", $table, $implodeArray, $_POST['id']);
```

in this case you used timestamp as a columnname so you needed to quote it

To update timestamps automatically you can rely on mysql itself if you only have 1 timestamp column or you can add `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` when defining your timestamp column, for more info see [TIMESTAMP initialisation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html)

Comment: MySQL permits `TIMESTAMP` as an unquoted identifier.  See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html.

Comment: yea thats what i thought as well

Comment: And please read this: [PHP: SQL Injection](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)

Comment: did the on update current_timestamp... but like i said it just works when i am updating from phpmyadmin and not my script

Comment: if timestamp is not the name of your column then why use that in your sql statement? You're asking mysql to set a column that doesn't exist. Don't you get an error?

Comment: no i dont. maybe im not understanding you correctly. should i change the column name to timestamp?

Comment: no, not at all. I just assumed you posted the actual code you used, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the timestamp every time something happens to the record (i.e. last modified date/time) then it is best to leave it fro the DB. You can not rely on default value in field definition because it will work only on INSERT (when the record/field is created), use
SET last_modified=GETDATE() [or GETUTCDATE()]
the actual functions may differ depending on your actual SQL server.

And "Ivan Buttinoni" is absolutely correct and nobody, including me, noticed it before - your field name is wrong, but the above comments still apply.

Answer (score 0):

If you have something like Framework that does not allow to "now()" this field - just make field to NOT NULL and set PHP variable (model->field) to null just before saving..